# Where does MinGW/Cygwin convert environment variables to Windows style?

Tags: windows, bash, environment-variables, cygwin

If you are in a Cygwin or MinGW bash shell, environment variables like $PATH are in "UNIX" format - using forward slashes as dir separators and using the colon to separate multiple paths. But if, inside this shell, you run something like `cmd.exe /c 'echo %PATH%'` the resulting output is in "Windows" format, using backslashes and semicolons respectively.

Is this magical conversion documented somewhere? Or better yet, can somebody point to the code that makes this happen?

(The reason I ask is because it seems the conversion doesn't always happen and I'm trying to understand the exact conditions needed for it to occur.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal conversions between Unix and Windows path format are
performed by the funtions in `path.cc`

https://cygwin.com/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=winsup/cygwin/path.cc;h=3cb46c9c812e17460d56def2f915b21c7227f3bf;hb=HEAD

When a Cygwin program executes a Windows program the spawn process is 
performed by functions in spawn.cc

https://cygwin.com/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=winsup/cygwin/spawn.cc;h=37db52608e24e866e80401668ef13562f0cb67ea;hb=HEAD

If you need more details or ask clarification use the cygwin mailing list.